# Moving SP-Linq queries from test site to production site

Tags: linq, sharepoint

I see articles on using SPMetal to generate the .cs file that allows LINQ to work properly. The file I'm talking about inherits from the Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataContext class. How can I use LINQ without recompiling on my production environment, since I would need to regenerate this file using SPMetal on my production environment? I suspect the answer is going to be "can't do it".

I guess I'll use a CAML query instead unless there is some easier way to use LINQ that I am missing.

Comment: Why would recompilation be a problem?

Comment: This seems like a common issue with Sharepoint. I dont understand how MS failed to address people working in multiple environments. A complete PITA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objective is just to query lists using LINQ and you want to avoid such recompilations, do not use SPMetal.
LINQ can be directly used on SPListItemCollection
e.g.

```
 var FindCustomer = from SPListItem Item in Customers.Items
                       where Item["Orders"] as int == 5
                        select Item;
```

//or select new{Title = Item["Title"]}

This does not have hard coded entities but is more flexible. And as long as your list column names remain same, code can be deployed on any environment even if other lists are changing.
Also you can choose to retrieve few chosen field's data instead of retrieving data of all the fields every time.

Comment: What is "ApplicationList" and ApplicationList.Items? What is Common.ApplicationListFields.APPLICATIONID? Assuming my SPList is named Customers and my column name is Orders and I want to retrieve all Customers with Orders = 5, please reformat the above code. I don't intend to be lazy but I think that will help me understand how this applies to what I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: Have modified code to your scenario. what you get in result is a enumerable variable. You can add .ToLis<SPListItems>() to the var to get a generic list of SPListItem. Or you can go for anonymous type by using select new{Title = Item["Title"], Orders = Item["Orders"]}

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem I guess. Personally I have been using Linq for good amount of time. I never generated the cs specifically for production. Is your site different across environments?

Comment: Yes, you got it. The site is not identical across environments. I suppose I can change the .cs file to account for differences manually. I wish there was a way to just use my select statement and have it work without the extra file. If I'm saying "select x from customers where blah blah" and I already provided the URL, it would be feasible for that to work. But that unfortunately is not how LINQ works.

Comment: Even if we go to relational world of databases, you would expect similarity in data structures across your environments. You can't write for a completely unrelated data structure. I guess it's more worrying as to why the data structures are not same across environments. I mean what use case drives them to be different.

Comment: There is similarity. The lists are both document libraries, the name is the same, and the column name and type are the same. All I am saying is that it would be convenient if that was the only information necessary to query that list. Perhaps I need to dig deeper into SPMetal to generate this info though.

Comment: I have successfully used it across environments without regenerating the entities.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I'm missing the point or not, but the DataContext object takes the URL as apart of the constructor, so you should retrieve the URL from config somewhere E.g. database

```
DataContext teamSite = new DataContext("http://MarketingServer/SalesTeam");
```

OR use the SPContext object, if your code has a SharePoint context. E.g. in a web part

```
DataContext teamSite = new DataContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
```

Comment: Yeah you did miss the point but that's ok. Point was that my environments are somewhat different. LINQ provides no way AFAIK to account for different test and production environments. My only solution that I'm seeing would be to manually edit the .cs file produced by SPMetal and change it so that it matches the production environment. Not worth it IMO.